# Jekyll not processing plugins on server

Tags: plugins, jekyll

Jekyll is processing my _plugins folder fine on my local machine (OS X 10.7.4, ruby 1.9.3), but it's not processing them on the server (Ubuntu 12.04, ruby 1.9.3). Both have the same version of Jekyll installed (0.11.2).

I'm trying to use the generate_sitemap plugin, [here](http://recursive-design.com/projects/jekyll-plugins/).

I'm deploying via git and the post-receive hook, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

GIT_REPO=/my_repo.git
TMP_GIT_CLONE=/my_temp_folder/
PUBLIC_WWW=/my_public_folder/

git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
jekyll --no-auto $TMP_GIT_CLONE $PUBLIC_WWW
rm -Rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
exit
```

I am seeing this error when I deploy:

```
remote: /home/ed/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
```

But, from what I've read, that's a Maruku warning and has nothing to do with the plugins.

Anybody have any ideas about what I can try to figure this out? I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Follow up questions: 1) If you run jekyll directly via the command line on the server, do the plugins work? If so, it may be the way the bash script is trying to run it. 2) Have you tried another plugin to see if it works? The thinking being that if another plugin works on the server it would help you narrow down the specifics of what's not working.

Comment: Good idea. When run directly from the command line on the server, the plugins are working. So it must be something in that script. But I'm not sure what it might be. The script isn't doing anything particularly complicated.

Comment: I need to modify that response somewhat. If I git clone a repository into a directory, then cd into that directory, and then run 'jekyll', the plugins work. However, if I git clone a repository into a directory and then run 'jekyll /my_tmp/ /my_public/' the plugins aren't processed. So it would appear there's something broken in the jekyll command that won't process the plugins if you give it directories as arguments.

Comment: Odd. One option would be to try using a relative path instead of one from the root (i.e. not starting with "/"). Another option would be to add a "cd /full/path/to/jekyll/source" line in the bash script and see if that works. If so, you may have to move your destination dir into the _config.yml file. (https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, since it breaks the plugins on the local server, but:If you set the plugins variable in _config.yml to the path where the plugins are temporarily located while the site is being built on the server, then the plugins will work on the server. In my case: 'plugins: /my_temp_folder/_plugins'. Perhaps this is a bug or limitation in Jekyll? Thanks for your help, Alan.

Answer (score 6):

It's very hard to debug with Jekyll, but it's a great tool !!!

I assume you have more than one plugin in your _plugins folder.

So maybe one or some of your plugins , cause the problem.

If I'm right, you can do the following :

- Kill your Jekyll
- Create a backup of your plugins in another location (not in _plugins
  folder).
- Leave just one plugin in your _plugins folder and start Jekyll.
- If it works , copy another plugin to the _plugins folder, until you
  find the one which fails the Jekyll.

When you find it, you can add debug printouts to the problematic plugin (that's what I did).

Something like : 
***puts "before .... "***

I have built the http://www.cloudifysource.org/ only with Jekyll and you can find and use lots of our useful examples in our GitHub repo : https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudifysource.github.com

Answer (score 2):

Lately, I start to build https://github.com/alswl/code-standards-jekyll with jekyll.
I write two plugins in `_plugins`, and I found it was hard to debug.

At first, I use `puts "balabala"` to debug, it seems work.But once I met problem that didn't generate anything in the `_site` folder, and there was no 'balabala' in the console, I was panic.

After I read the jekyll source, I try to set `auto=false` in `_config.yml`, running jekyll will produce some debug trace stack error. Thank godness.

So, ues `auto=false` will help you to debug plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Jekyll not loading plugins when called from the post-receive hook.

As is mentioned in the comments above, changing the current working directory to `$TMP_GIT_CLONE` does the trick.

You don't have to change anything in _config.yml.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -l

GIT_REPO=/my_repo.git
TMP_GIT_CLONE=/my_temp_folder/
PUBLIC_WWW=/my_public_folder/

git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
cd $TMP_GIT_CLONE                             # move to the temp dir
jekyll --no-auto $TMP_GIT_CLONE $PUBLIC_WWW
cd                                            # move back to allow deletion
rm -Rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
exit
```

This is a real head-scratcher seeing as executing the original post-receive hook manually as the git user works just fine... Anyway, Jekyll is now loading plugins on my server and hopefully making this a proper answer will help others to find this solution.